# How to Bind Click Event to ViewModel when creating control in code

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

Typically, I create the view in XAML, and bind events to the viewmodel using Caliburn.Micro.

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[MouseLeftButtonUp]=[ModifyList($source)]" />
```

However, I now need to create the button in code, based on configuration data.

The code is not in the code-behind, it's in a factory class.

```
Button button = new Button() { Content = "Click Me" };
```

So the question is how to wire up the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done this before, so this might not be the *best* way, but it does appear to work.

I've written an extension method below that should make it pretty simple to attach an ActionMessage to any event of any control.

```
public static class UIElementExtension {
    public static void AttachActionMessage(this DependancyObject control, string eventName, string methodName, object parameter) {
        var action = new ActionMessage();
        action.MethodName = methodName;
        action.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Value = parameter });

        var trigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger();
        trigger.EventName = eventName;
        trigger.SourceObject = control;
        trigger.Actions.Add(action);

        Interaction.GetTriggers(control).Add(trigger);
    }
}
```

To use it, simply create your control and call `AttachActionMessage()`:

```
var button = new Button { Content = "Click Me" };
button.AttachActionMessage("Click", "ModifyList", DataContext);
```

Comment: Excellent. This is just what I had in mind, but wasn't sure how to get there.

Comment: I've updated it now to an extension method of UIElement. Makes it a little cleaner, and makes reuse a snap.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting an exception, you have to only add the parameter when it is not null and the method accept exactly one parameter.

Short answer add this check:

```
if (parameter != null)
{
    action.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Value = parameter });
}
```

Or, you can use this improved version of the original accepted answer. With this, you can pass any number of arguments or null, depending on the parameters of the method:

```
public static void AttachActionMessage(this DependencyObject control, string eventName, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    var action = new ActionMessage { MethodName = methodName };

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            action.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Value = parameter });
        }
    }

    var trigger = new System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
    {
        EventName = eventName,
        SourceObject = control
    };
    trigger.Actions.Add(action);

    Interaction.GetTriggers(control).Add(trigger);
}
```

The code is tested with these methods and working:

```
IncrementCountButton.AttachActionMessage("Click", "IncrementCount", null);
IncrementCountButton2.AttachActionMessage("Click", "IncrementCount2", 12);

public void IncrementCount()
{
    Count++;
}

public void IncrementCount2(int value)
{
    Count += value;
}
```